# Slider in fullscreen columns bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good afternoon everyone.

I am using the bootstrap 3 and am facing a problem that I am not able to deal with more than one week. I have a layout that has 1 column for menu and other 11 to be a fullscreen slider. I've tried using various techniques but nothing work. Someone has to help me?

I was trying with this, but I also used other without much success

Follow the link the example of the layout and the simple code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfGBE.jpg -> Sample layout

sample code that was using

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems.

First your columns are meant to be wrapped in a .row, you can just add a 'row' to your 'content-fluid' class as that's the parent div.

Secondly, you're using background images (by default, it works with normal img tags), with no specific height on the parent divs. (height: 100% isn't a specific height)

Simple quick fix is just by defining a height for the .item class.

http://www.bootply.com/7ZJXwMETXq

Comment: hi, thank you for help, only one thing that did not work, the height was fixed at 400 px the item. I put one js to calculate automatically and worked author.

look: http://www.bootply.com/sEwyeYnbH1

Comment: @LuisFernandoMangia well yeah, that works but I wouldn't really suggest  using js to do something like that. I would rather ensure that the images i'm using are all the same height by resizing them appropriately and then set .item to be that height